# How to make the Player GameObject transform after animation ends

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm making a 2D game in **Unity**, within which, a player can 'teleport' to a location after they click on a teleport-able GameObject. The problem is, I've set an animation to first play before the player's GameObject actually transforms to a different coordinate. That animation plays, however, I need to know when that animation ends so I can finally execute that transform command.

I am using the `Animator` property as of now. The desired flow should be

`IDLE -> Pre Teleport Animation -> Teleport -> Post Teleport Animation -> IDLE`

So it is clear that need to know of a way that tells me when `Pre Teleport Animation` ends so I can transform the player. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could attach an AnimationEvent to the animation clip. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationEvent.html